# Entity Framework Core not updating existing tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

I have an IdentityServer that uses EntityFramework Core.
I use the code-first approach. Every time i want to edit the database, such as adding tables or adding more columns to any existing table, I just perform those changes in code and then in package manager console I use the commands to create the migration files.
When i run the IdentityServer, it has the following piece of code that performs the migrations.

```
GlobalConfig.DatabaseConnectionString = configuration.GetValue<string>("DatabaseConnectionString");

var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>().UseSqlServer(GlobalConfig.DatabaseConnectionString);

using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options))
    {
        context.Database.Migrate();
    }
```

'ApplicationDbContext' is just the class that extends IdentityDbContext and implements IApplicationDbContext.

Back to the main point, the

```
 context.Database.Migrate();
```

applies the new migrations if I create a new database, and even with an existing database it applies the new changes.

Now is where the problem occurs. If I delete the columns or tables just added after the migration, if I run the program again, it will not perform the changes again. And why is this a problem?

I run the migration in my localmachine an it performs the migrations and updates the databases, but when someone pulls (in my particular case, my company's QA) my solution and runs the program, it does not perform that migrations on their machines.

I would like to know what am I doing wrong, or if that is something normal in EntityFramework.

I would like that the EF could check the database first and if it is not equal as specified in code, apply the changes... or something similar.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please take a good look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then edit your question to make it answerable.

Comment: EF does not run a full schema check every time it tries to access the database. After model creation, it checks the __MigrationHistory table to see if the schema hash has the expected value. You likely didn't reset the __MigrationHistory table but only altered the schema, so EF didn't notice the schema changed since it's place to check said it was up to date. That's at least how I understand the question, if not, please edit it.

Comment: Hi, what is your question?

Comment: Thanks you all guys for trying to help. Have to admit it was kinda confusing. I rewrote my question. Hope it is understandable now =)